# Validation Rule Syntax error missing - Formula

Tags: validation-rule, validation, automation, service

I have created the below validation rule but when saving it shows
Error: Syntax error. Found ')' 
Can someone help me identify what I am missing

OR( 
AND( 
$User.Full_Name__c <> "Case Guest User", 
$UserRole.Name <> "CAN-SFISVC",
ISCHANGED(FIRST_CONTACT_RESOLUTION__c),
FIRST_CONTACT_RESOLUTION__c = true,
),
AND( 
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) <> TODAY(), 
TEXT(Status) = 'Reopened', 
Ownership_Change_Count__c > 0, 
OwnerShip_Change_Count_Queue__c > 0, 
Case_Re_open_Count__c > 0 
) 
)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `,` at the end in the line `FIRST_CONTACT_RESOLUTION__c = true` in first `AND()` condition as below

```
OR(
AND(
$User.Full_Name__c <> "Case Guest User",
$UserRole.Name <> "CAN-SFISVC",
ISCHANGED(FIRST_CONTACT_RESOLUTION__c),
FIRST_CONTACT_RESOLUTION__c = true
),
AND(
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) <> TODAY(),
TEXT(Status) = 'Reopened',
Ownership_Change_Count__c > 0,
OwnerShip_Change_Count_Queue__c > 0,
Case_Re_open_Count__c > 0
)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me save the rule.

Comment: Hello all, So i created the validation rule for 2 requirements which is
1. The above rule should fire for users with Role = CAN-SFISVC where only for this role they should be able to close the case same day as the created date.  However The below requirement is not working as expected. 
2. The rule should not let users close the case unless its created the same day for that particluar role alone. But the validation rule is letting the same role users close the case next day or day after that which it should not. Can someone help me to figure this out. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AmandaGreen - you should ask that as a new question; accept swetha's answer